# Create KeycloakBuilder object in Keycloak returns java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/admin/client/KeycloakBuilder

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to create KeycloakBuilder object using code below:

```
KeycloakBuilder keycloakBuilder = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                                                  .realm(realmId)
                                                  .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                                                  .clientId(clientId)
                                                  .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                  .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
```

But I get Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/admin/client/KeycloakBuilder

**How can I solve this problem?**

This is my dependecies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the value for `keycloak.version`? Also, the dependency tree would help to figure out the problem

Comment: Keycloak version 15.0.2

Comment: Actually, I solved it by adding the "keycloak-admin-client" module to the Keycloak folder. But is there a way to solve this problem with a pom file or some configuration in the custom SPI. Because I can't add anything to the prod Keycloak folder.